# Noty example with velocity - velocity() undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this example from Noty's site: http://ned.im/noty/animations.bouncejs.html

I have installed noty.js and its CSS counter part.  And I also have downloaded velocity.js and have it linked properly in my site.  I know it is linked properly because I can use JQuery to select an element and perform a function on it that is provided by velocity:

```
$("table").velocity("fadeOut", {
    duration: 3500
});
```

The example that is provided on the noty site though uses a call formatted like this:

```
new Noty({
text: 'NOTY - animating with velocity!',
animation: {
    open: function () {
        var n = this;
        Velocity(n.barDom, {
            left: 450,
            scaleY: 2
        }, {
            duration: 0
        });
        Velocity(n.barDom, {
            left: 0,
            scaleY: 1
        }, {
            easing: [ 8, 8 ]
        });
    },
```

It calls it by using Velocity(...  when I put this code into my page it errors and using the chrome F12 it says it is undefined.  What am I missing from the example?  The example for bounce works but I don't like the movement as much.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the developer we found an issue with the declaration on his site.  Velocity doesn't work the way it is called in the question.  It needs to be declared with $.Velocity with the current version of NOTY & Velocity

```
new Noty({
text: 'NOTY - animating with velocity!',
animation: {
    open: function () {
        var n = this;
        $.Velocity(n.barDom, {
            left: 450,
            scaleY: 2
        }, {
            duration: 0
        });
        $.Velocity(n.barDom, {
            left: 0,
            scaleY: 1
        }, {
            easing: [ 8, 8 ]
        });
    },
```